# How to transfer large number of files within ADLS Gen2/Blob using Databricks?

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, databricks

I need to transfer a decent amount(100k+) files almost everyday using azure databricks from a folder to another on ADLS Gen2, dbutils.fs.ls is not parallel and hence takes a lot more time than I can afford. Anyway to transfer it efficiently? I have tried creating a dataframe out of the files and running dbutils.fs.ls in a map or foreach of that dataframe but it does not work and gives the error -

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 10 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 10.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 375, 10.139.64.4, executor 0): java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs

- Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 10 in stage 13.0 failed 4
  times, most recent failure: Lost task 10.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 375,
  10.139.64.4, executor 0): java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs

I have also added the following configuration based on my findings and added the required jar to my cluster, still gives the same error.
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")

Entire stack trace -

```
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$.getFS(DBUtilsCore.scala:251)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$$anonfun$cp$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(DBUtilsCore.scala:114)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$$anonfun$cp$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(DBUtilsCore.scala:113)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$.com$databricks$backend$daemon$dbutils$FSUtils$$withFsSafetyCheck(DBUtilsCore.scala:81)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$$anonfun$cp$1.apply(DBUtilsCore.scala:113)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$$anonfun$cp$1.apply(DBUtilsCore.scala:113)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$.com$databricks$backend$daemon$dbutils$FSUtils$$withFsSafetyCheck(DBUtilsCore.scala:81)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$.cp(DBUtilsCore.scala:112)
at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.DbfsUtilsImpl.cp(DbfsUtilsImpl.scala:45)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(command-3171921041650758:1)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(command-3171921041650758:1)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(command-3171921041650758:1)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(command-3171921041650758:1)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:987)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:987)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2323)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2323)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:537)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:543)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2362)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2350)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2349)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1102)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2582)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2529)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2517)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:897)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2282)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2304)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2323)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2348)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:987)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:985)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:392)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:985)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply$mcV$sp(Dataset.scala:2810)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2810)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2810)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$withNewRDDExecutionId$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3477)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:243)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:173)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewRDDExecutionId(Dataset.scala:3473)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreachPartition(Dataset.scala:2809)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3171921041650758:1)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3171921041650758:46)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3171921041650758:48)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3171921041650758:50)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3171921041650758:52)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw.<init>(command-3171921041650758:54)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read.<init>(command-3171921041650758:56)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$.<init>(command-3171921041650758:60)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$.<clinit>(command-3171921041650758)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:714)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:667)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:396)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:373)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:275)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:373)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$.getFS(DBUtilsCore.scala:251)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$$anonfun$cp$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(DBUtilsCore.scala:114)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$$anonfun$cp$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(DBUtilsCore.scala:113)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$.com$databricks$backend$daemon$dbutils$FSUtils$$withFsSafetyCheck(DBUtilsCore.scala:81)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$$anonfun$cp$1.apply(DBUtilsCore.scala:113)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$$anonfun$cp$1.apply(DBUtilsCore.scala:113)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$.com$databricks$backend$daemon$dbutils$FSUtils$$withFsSafetyCheck(DBUtilsCore.scala:81)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils$.cp(DBUtilsCore.scala:112)
at com.databricks.dbutils_v1.impl.DbfsUtilsImpl.cp(DbfsUtilsImpl.scala:45)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(command-3171921041650758:1)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(command-3171921041650758:1)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(command-3171921041650758:1)
at line6cd233c6e76046b688ada150c95cd077118.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(command-3171921041650758:1)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:987)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:987)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2323)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2323)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:140)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:537)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1541)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:543)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: why not use Azure Data Factory for that?

Answer (score 0):

**"java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs"** is a Azure Blob configuration issue, you need to configure your Azure ADLS connection and libs.